# Couldnt Overhaul be used in the same way of Eri's rewind quirk?

Tags: my-hero-academia

According to one My Hero Academia wikia

> he is also capable of using it to "revive" people, as he has done to Rappa multiple times

and

> Sir Nighteye assumes that Chisaki's Quirk is responsible for the healing of the Team Reservoir Dogs

Also

> Overhaul's characters in his name are composed of "治" (chi, lit.
>   "govern, regulate, administer"), "崎" (saki, lit. "promontory, cape,
>   spit") and "廻" (kai, lit. "revolve, **return**, curving"

If he can revive and may be heal people, isnt reving the most difficult/extreme "rewind" of a person's state? Couldnt Overhaul be used in the same way of Eri's rewind quirk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to description of Overhaul ability, it allows its user to disassemble and reassemble anything, which makes it kinda similar to alchemy from Fullmetal Alchemist. This leads me to speculation, that while disassembling something or someone, Kai Chisaki learns how this object or person is structured, and thus is able to reconstruct it or them to the previous shape. This is partially backed up by the fact, that most of people, that were "revived" by Kai Chisaki, were killed by his ability as well.

Description of Eri's ability is rather vague, but it seems she can just "rewind" person to previous state (it is still not clear what "parameters" of person she can "rewind"), even being not aware what this state was. Another difference is that according to situation when

> Midoriya was using 100% Full Cowl for pretty extended time,

Eri is able to "fix" person in their current "state", instantly reverting any changes to their body, unlike Overhaul, which is singular action.

Most limitations to quirks are never explained by author, but taking into account, that Kai Chisaki was never using his quirk to achieve same result as Eri is able to do, I'd say he can't "simulate" it.

Answer (score 0):

Quirks are somewhat related to DNA and blood. Quirks are also like a muscle in the human body; Overusing them can be strainful, Quirk can be trained to become more efficient, just like a muscle, and last, but not least, they have limits, and guess what also has limits? I'll give you a hint: A GODDAMN MUSCLE.

But, it's also about what the Quirk effects in question. In all honesty, even a random Quirk might be related to everything in the human body. Kai, with Overhaul, has been shown to turn straight-up blood into solid, non-organic bullets that can remove Quirks. This means that he could literally create bullets with different effects that are related to the quirk's ability. And, it's already been said that the quirk itself has full control over matter when reassembling something, whether it be organic or non-organic. And, this also may or may not be true, I'm not sure, but Kai could fuse himself with people by using Overhaul to disassemble himself and then reassemble the person's body, giving him control over their Quirk(s).

If Kai could do all of that, then I'm sure he would be able to remove someone's Quirk by disassembling and reassembling them to where the Quirk didn't even exist at all in the human body, or even in their DNA. In fact, you could probably make someone younger with this Quirk, or augment or decrease the power of a Quirk. Basically, the Quirk can disassemble something and reassemble matter in any form or shape, which is just OP as hell.

Comment: Hello, @Demonetization could you please cite your sources for your answer? You can add links or image to prove your point more concretely.